# Responsive sticky sidebar

Tags: jquery, sidebar

I have a responsive sidebar for my website. It is supposed to be starting it's css change from 'static' to 'fixed' when the top of the screen reaches the element minus 10px. It works allright for me here on my laptop screen, but when I resize the window to a more tablet like resolution it doensn't start where it should. You can view the result [here](http://www.creativecodes.be/filip/pagina.html).

The code i have is the following:

```
var obj = $('#menu');
var offset = obj.offset();
var topOffset = offset.top;
var leftOffset = offset.left;
var marginTop = obj.css("marginTop");
var marginLeft = obj.css("marginLeft");

$(window).scroll(function() {





    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var px = $("#menu").height();


if (scrollTop >= (topOffset + px)){
    obj.css({
            marginTop: 0,
            top: 20,
            position: 'fixed',
        });
    } else
if (scrollTop < topOffset + px){        obj.css({           marginTop: marginTop,           marginLeft: marginLeft,             position: 'static',         });     } 
});
```

Comment: well, have you tried refreshing it when you are on smaller window? the javascript/jquery initializes at page load when it thinks its on bigger screen and when you resize the screen, the javascript doesn't know it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use media query?  Also I recommend not leaving a trailing ',' in your .css() list.

```
@media (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  #YOUR_ELE_ID {
    marginTop: 0;
    top: 20;
    position: 'fixed';
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is, that when I resize (and reload), the #menu div doesn't start being fixed untill I'm halfway the menu which isn't the issue on a higher resolution screen like mine

Comment: That's why you add multiple media queries, with multiple conditions.  I just gave an example.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the selector.  It now reflects the proper format.